# Excel - Get Location of Offset Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The `Offset()` function returns the contents of some cell. How can I get the location of it instead (eg 'A1')? Preferably in a formula, not VBA. I'm hoping something like Cell(offset()) exists, but I haven't been able to find anything like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is -

```
=CELL("address",OFFSET(A1,1,1))
```

will return

```
$B$2
```